# Sequelize: How to return relationships as JSON attribute?

Tags: json, database, orm, sequelize.js

I have a simple database of `articles` and `authors`.

Each `article` is connected to `author(s)` through a `belongsToMany` relationship, for example:

**Articles**

```
id: 1
title: Test
```

**Authors**

```
id: 1
name: Foo

id: 2
name: Bar
```

Say, for example, that the `article` is joined to *both* authors.

Using sequelize, how can I have `Articles.findAll()` return the authors along with its details, for example:

```
"articles": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Test",
    "author_ids": "[1,2]"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [include option](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#relations-associations) in your query:

```
Articles.findAll({
  include: [Author]
}).then(function(articles) {
  console.log(articles[0].authors[0].author_id);
});
```